# How to remove shortcuts of drives from desktop without unmounting it in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unmount, gconf

I have a question about *un*mounting the drives in Linux.

Whenever I open any drives in system its shortcut/image will be shown in the desktop. To remove that, I need to right-click on it and select unmount.

Then only that shortcut disappears. This always happens.  So whenever I open any drive all of them would be there in desktop.  What I need is for this not to happen.  What can I do to achieve that? Can anyone help?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.  Previously I used 10.10 then the same problem was also there.

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question at askubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/27392/hide-mounted-volume-icon-on-the-desktop I would recommend posting Ubuntu specific question there in the future.

Comment: @EricG Ubuntu questions are on topic here—it's perfectly fine to post them on Super User. We don't migrate on-topic questions away; see [Is it okay to inform users to stop promoting Apple.SE when a question is fine to stay here?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2967/is-it-okay-to-inform-users-to-stop-promoting-apple-se-when-a-question-is-fine-to) (same for Ubuntu)

Comment: @slhck, the bigger issue was it was a duplicate question, but its not on the list for dup questions in th flag; I see this question is generally enough to work here too.

Comment: @EricG Ask Ubuntu and Super User are absolutely unrelated in that regard. If there are questions about the same things on both sites, so be it. It's not an issue, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was addressed on Ask Ubuntu a few times, here is [a post with some screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NuZW.png) that may be useful:

> 1. Press Alt-F2 and enter `gconf-editor`.
> 2. Navigate to apps/nautilus/desktop.
> 3. Deselect volumes_visible.
>      [image: gconf-editor]
>
> If you want your other volumes to be visible, you will have to add them manually:
>
> 1. Right click on desktop and click 'Create Launcher...'
> 2. Change the type to 'Location'
> 3. Change the name to suit you.
> 4. Browse for the volume.
> 5. Change the icon to the 'block device' icon at `/usr/share/icons/YOUR_THEME/devices/48/block-device.svg`
> 6. Click OK.
>
>    [image: launcher]

Comment: but in nautilus folder only preference is present.I think i need to install something else.can u tell me what is it?

Answer (score 2):

This can be removed by Changing a value in `Gnome-configuration-Editor`

Run `gconf-editor`

if dont have it install it by `apt-get install gconf-editor`

after opening go to  `apps->nautilus->desktop` and uncheck

Comment: but which value?

Comment: @sreevisakh In nautilus folder only preference folder is present in my system.I think i need to install something else.can you tell me what is it?

Comment: if you cant find them use the commandline tool `gconf-tool2` to set the values

Comment: @Sreevisakh while entering that command it showing command not found!!!

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install gconf-editor`

Answer (score 0):

To turn off showing mounts in the Ubuntu 22.04, I used the solution described [here](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/11/hide-mounted-drives-left-dock-ubuntu-19-10/). It is as running following command in the terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-mounts false
```